# Is there a way to use less than on Strings?

Tags: c#, .net

Using a string.CompareTo(string) i can get around this slightly but is not easy to read and i have read on that locallity settings might influence the result.

Is there a way to just simply use < or > on 2 Strings in a more straightforward way?

Comment: And then locality settings would still matter, without a way to control them

Comment: And what do you expect as a result?
The same as `string1.CompareTo(string2) < 0`?

Comment: @DanielH yes, just a boolean.
@Henk Holterman I never tought of that, your point is a very good one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can overload operators but you seldom should. To me `"stringA" > "stringB"` wouldn't mean a damn thing, it's not helping readability IMO. That's why operator overloading guidelines advise not to overload operators if the meaning is not obvious.

EDIT: [Operator Overloading Usage Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2sk3x8a7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Also, in case of `String` I'm afraid you can't do it seeing as you can put operator-overloading methods only in the class in which the methods are defined. 
If the syntax of `CompareTo` bothers you, maybe wrapping it in extension method will solve your problem?

Like that:

```
public static bool IsLessThan(this string str, string str2) {
    return str.Compare(str2) < 0;
}
```

I still find it confusing for reader though.
The bottom line is, you can't overload operators for `String`. Usually you can do something like declaring a partial and stuffing your overloads there, but `String` is a sealed class, so not this time. I think that the extension method with reasonable name is your best bet. You can put `CompareTo` or some custom logic inside it.

Comment: IMO, using Strings for ranges and then having to see whats the lowest is a bad thing (i dislike legaccy code at times). But your right that A > B being more or less readable is subjectivly only true for some.

Comment: @Andy: So you're using strings to store numeric values? Why not parse them to an `int` first before doing the comparison?

Comment: The Strings have a prefix so A100 would be in front of B001. And since it is a legaccy app there is no spec on how long the prefix is or what A and B mean, but from analysing the old vb6 app it does string < string

Comment: @Andy: then your best bet is extension method with your own logic or with `CompareTo` inside, see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

CompareTo is the proper way in my opinion, you can use the overloads to specify culture specific parameters...

Answer (score 2):

You mention in a comment that you're comparing two strings with values of the form "A100" and "B001". This works in your legacy VB 6 code with the `<` and `>` operators because of the way that VB 6 implements string comparison.

The algorithm is quite simple. It walks through the string, one character at a time, and compares the ASCII values of each character. As soon as a character from one string is found to have a lower ASCII code than the corresponding character in the other string, the comparison stops and the first string is declared to be "less than" the second. (VB 6 can be forced to perform a case-insensitive comparison based on the system's current locale by placing the `Option Compare Text` statement at the top of
the relevant code module, but this is *not* the default setting.)

Simple, of course, but not entirely *logical*. Comparing ASCII values skips over all sorts of interesting things you might find in strings nowadays; namely non-ASCII characters. Since you appear to be dealing with strings whose contents have pre-defined limits, this may not be a problem in your particular case. But more generally, writing code like `strA < strB` is going to look like complete nonsense to anyone else who has to maintain your code (it seems like you're already *having* this experience), and I encourage you to do the "right thing" even when you're dealing with a fixed set of possible inputs.

There is nothing "straightforward" about using `<` or `>` on string values. If you need to implement this functionality, you're going to have to do it yourself. Following the algorithm that I described VB 6 as using above, you could write your own comparison function and call that in your code, instead. Walk through each character in the string, determine if it is a character or a number, and convert it to the appropriate data type. From there, you can compare the two parsed values, and either move on to the next index in the string or return an "equality" value.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the non-ASCII characters problem can be solved somehow by passing some options in `CompareTo` overloads, but still a good point about .NET `CompareTo` not acting like operators in VB 6

Comment: @Dyppl: Yeah, you can use `CompareTo` to do this, but it seemed to me like the asker was specifically trying to *avoid* using it. (Not sure why, though, so that's still a good point.)

Comment: I think what he was trying to do was encapsulate `CompareTo` inside the body of comparison operator or somewhere else so it's still this method that does the work

Comment: "the way that VB 6 implements string comparison" - actually VB6 comparison isn't always ordinal - it's controlled by the "Option Compare" statement - can be Binary (Ordinal), Text (case-insensitive using current culture) or Database (used within Microsoft Access).

Comment: @Joe: Yes, that's true. Although the default setting is Option Compare Binary. Since we're not in a database, one can assume that Option Compare Database is not relevant (that's also VBA, not VB 6).

Answer (score 1):

There is another problem with that, I think:

```
Assert.IsFalse(10 < 2);  
Assert.IsTrue("10" < "2");
```

(The second Assert assumes you did an overload for the `<` operator on the string class.)
But the operator suggests otherwise!!
I agree with Dyppl: you shouldn't do it!